# gzip compression ratio of an ASCII file

Tags: compression, ascii, gzip, image-compression

So I have a [remote sensing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2gwd.png) in an ASCII format packed as *.gz


Packed file has 7.46 MB
Unpacked file has 635 MB

What is the reason for that? Is it a matter of gzip compression method or a structure of an ASCII file?

Comment: It just means that GZip works really well for text files (and that's a good thing). Your data is probably very repetitive (especially if the format also includes field names for every row).

Comment: What format is it exactly, PPM? Anyway the compression ratio on text files (which use a limited alphabet) can be very high. If your picture has some patterns (like, a part is completely black) an uncompressed format can waste a lot of bytes to encode the same information (black pixel, black pixel, black pixel...). In these cases the savings can be huge. So it's both due to Gzip being good and the original format being really inefficient.

Comment: I edited the post with a link to the image. Yes, indeed it has vast areas with  same value of a pixel plus black no data as well.

Comment: How is this an ASCII image?

Comment: It is obviously a screen from SAGA-GIS software, where I imported it. Remote sensing images are sometimes distributed in `.asc` format and this is a screen from such a file. A few words on it here: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Comment: @WattsInABox ASCII formatted binary conversion is relatively simple: 1) expand all bytes to nibbles (e.g. 0xAB becomes {0x0A, 0x0B}), 2) add '0' (0x30) to every value less than 0x0A, 3) add 'A' - 0x41 (0x37) to all other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three factors:

1. Fundamentally, the image is highly structured. It requires much less
   information to exactly replicate than a random image would.
2. Representing arbitrary binary data using ASCII characters always
   takes extra space, and this format is much less efficient than
   something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.
3. The DEFLATE algorithm in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip is pretty good.